# Explanation of cvSeqPartition()?

Tags: c++, opencv, sequences

I have no idea what this does could someone explain this to me in SIMPLE terms?
Please don't give me complicated mathematical answers or something too technical, just its general purpose
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// This function splits the input sequence or set into one or more equivalence classes.
// is_equal(a,b,...) returns non-zero if the two sequence elements
// belong to the same class.  The function returns sequence of integers -
// 0-based class indexes for each element.
//
// The algorithm is described in "Introduction to Algorithms"
// by Cormen, Leiserson and Rivest, chapter "Data structures for disjoint sets"
CV_IMPL  int
cvSeqPartition( const CvSeq* seq, CvMemStorage* storage, CvSeq** labels,
                CvCmpFunc is_equal, void* userdata )
```

What part requires more detailed explanation?

**Update:**

Foe example, consider the following sequence of integers:

```
{9,5,7,5,9,9}
```

When `is_equal` function just tests for integer equality, `cvSeqPartition` will find 3 classes:

```
{9,9,9} {5,5} {7}
```

so `cvSeqPartition` output will be

```
{0,1,2,1,0,0}
```

where each number is index of the element class.

Comment: so it just splits the sequence in two? is that it?

Comment: Not in two, but it finds all the equivalency classes. I've updated my answer with a simple example.